# background-image not positioned fixed on different devices

Tags: css, mobile, background-image, background-position

I built a website with a small background image in the right bottom.

On a desktop, the background image stays on the bottom when I scroll the page.

On an Android device, the background image scrolls up when I scroll the page. When I do a refresh in the middle of the page, the background image reappears in the right bottom of the current view.

On an iPad, the background image is shown only at the very bottom of the page.

For each of the tablet/phone sizes, I defined a separate background image, so that is not the problem.

See: http://www.zaanstuc.nl/onze-producten

The css:

```
background:#CFCFCF url('../images/pascal1.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

How can I get the image fixed in the right bottom corner on all devices: desktop, tablet and phone?

Comment: See the link to the site for the HTML. All images are linke to the id="page" or id="page2".

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your question is very vague.

Second of all, I think you have misunderstood `fixed`. If you set something to fixed, it has to come with your *scroll* movement. So if you scroll down, the background has to scroll down too. On desktop,  this is happening, but because your device is small, you don't have the same user experience on your mobile. In technique, however, it's the same.

If you want to position the image on the right, you could use this:

You can use `background-position: right bottom;`

PS: I noticed that you have 10 `body` and `#page2` elements in your CSS. They are not needed and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
1. background:#CFCFCF url('../images/pascal1.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%; is shorthand for several settings including background-position: right bottom;
100% 100% equals right bottom

2. I stated I defines seperate background images for the different device sizes. Why? it saves bandwith, loading time and so on. Seomd I use two different images. Both times 5 equals ten definitions.

So my question still stands: how can I get the images in all devices in the right hand bottom corner of the viewport.

Comment: You could use `media queries` to style them per device.

Comment: Thanks Siyah,
I allready do. Thats why I have so many #page and #page2 elements in the CSS.